# How to check a column contain non numeric values

Tags: unix, awk

I want get the count of non numeric records in a file for  particular column in `unix`.
I have tried:

`awk -F"|" ' $1~ "^[0-9]*$" { print $1 }' File |wc -l`

But no luck.
 Help Me.

Comment: what are you getting with the command you tried?

Comment: You are checking for numerical values in column one. And you could also use `awk`to do the counting, rather than pipe the output to another program.

Comment: You want to count non-numeric but yet you are looking at $1 for numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1}' File | awk '/^[0-9]$/' | wc -l
```

Comment: You could change that to: `awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]$/{c++};END{print c}' File`

Answer (score 5):

The only sensible way to check for numeric values is to do a math comparison:

```
awk -F"|" '($1=="") || ($1+0 != $1){print $1; cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' File
```

Comparing with `^[0-9]$` will fail for floating point or exponential numbers

Comment: Instead of 1 column could this be generalized to work with many columns? Because I see it's just looking at column 1.  But I think I could use cut command and get one column at a time, so maybe that's one answer to my question but maybe not most efficient.

Comment: Another enhancement: Ignore empty fields: How to do?  That is, if nothing appears between field delimiters, it is OK.  Simply removing the LHS test surprisingly did not work: ($=="") ||

Comment: Yes, it'd be trivial to work on multiple fields and to ignore empty fields. Post a new question.